# Bot Framework Orchestrator create snapshots at runtime / Orchestrate between multiple KBs

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a ChatBot using the Bot Framework SDK v4 with Orchestrator.

As per the docs, Orchestrator works by using a pretrained model to create a snapshot of .lu & .qna files, and then dispatches to the correct LUIS or QnAMaker service depending on user input by referring to the Orchestrator snapshot.

However, for my bot, which has several knowledge bases with several dozens of contributors this is a very tedious task. You have to export each knowledge base using the bf CLI via

```
bf qnamaker:kb:export -o filename.qna --kbId="mykbid" --qnaFormat
```

and then move the resulting .qna file into the CognitiveModels folder, then create the Orchestrator snapshot manually. Then I also have to redeploy the bot to Azure just to update the Orchestrator snapshot.

This means every time any knowledge base is updated I have to do this manually periodically in order to update the bot so that Orchestrator properly dispatches to the correct KB. I feel like this should be something that's automated during runtime. I don't see anywhere in the Docs a way to do this.

Since LUIS models aren't updated as regularly I thought that I could set the default case as the QnaMaker, so any unknown intents get mapped to QnAMaker by default and therefore the snapshot doesn't have to be updated as often. But the problem with that is if you have multiple QnAMaker KBs, there's no way to federate the KBs into a single QnAMaker endpoint (AFAIK; if it is possible this would solve my issue) so you have to rebuild Orchestrator snapshot to dispatch between different KB services as well.

Are there any suggestions on how to automate creating Orchestrator snapshots?

Comment: Were you were able to automate this? We got away from dispatcher by issuing queries against QNA and LUIS at the same time and then taking the highest ranked response. But now the company want to create a generic bot that would be able to answer any question, and querying dozens of QNA and LUIS apps for each request doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dmitriy
I stopped using Orchestrator. The snapshot is great for performance and not querying LUIS for dispatch, but it also lacks all of the features that LUIS utterances have such as entities and feature list. Its multilingual model doesn't work most of the time either (at least in Korean). 

I also compiled all QnA's into a single KB. It doesn't make sense design wise but since MS doesn't support federating QnA's this was the only solution. My dispatcher queries QnA by default when any intent isn't recognized, and if it doesn't meet a certain threshold it routes to unknown intent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no automated method of accomplishing this. If everything you need to do is in the CLI, you could write a script to automate the task for you, and either run it as needed or use something like cron to run it automatically (assuming the machine running the script is on at the specified time).