# Confusing Lack of Automation for Bot Framework Orchestrator

Tags: botframework

We are beginning to research Bot Framework Orchestrator and realized that the model is generated and deployed together with bot binaries to the Azure App Service. What this means that ANY change to our dozens of QNAs by our dozens of Content Managers would require rebulding an Orchestrator snapshot and deployment to Azure App Service.

As per below stackoverflow posts it seems there is no automation available for this process. At least with Dispatch the model was a LUIS app, so as long as LUIS app was updated your chatbot had an up to date way to find the right QNA for content, without deployment.

Can someone help to understand if there is something misunderstood about automation, or is it really lacking in current state?

[Bot Framework Orchestrator create snapshots at runtime / Orchestrate between multiple KBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70329263/bot-framework-orchestrator-create-snapshots-at-runtime-orchestrate-between-mul)
[Is it possible to refresh the Bot Framework Orchestrator model via Azure Pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69252612/is-it-possible-to-refresh-the-bot-framework-orchestrator-model-via-azure-pipelin)

EDIT: And with respect to snapshot, since when are we getting away from using REST API based cognitive services and starting to use pre-built static models? What was wrong with keeping the model in LUIS?

Answer (score 0):

We are in the same place place currently - due to QnA Maker becoming obsolete and our bot solution sitting on 2x LUIS + 2x QnA stitched together into LUIS Dispatch, we migrated QnA Maker to Custom Question Answering in Microsoft Language Studio, LUIS apps to Conversational Language Understanding, and - analogically - we created an Orchestration project to stitch them into one.

What was my surprise when I've discovered that there is analogical process in the chatbot code to query Custom Question Answering instead of QnA using Bot.Builder SDK, but the Orchestrator vs Dispatcher process is completely different.

Maybe I don't have the full picture here and honestly searching for information on the topic is really cumbersome (hands down to a note sitting on qnamaker.ai website that says "you won't be able to create QnA Maker resources, but will be able to create Knowledgebases on existing resources" but other notes in MS docs or Language Studio migration guide says "you won't be able to create neither QnA Maker resources nor new KBs") so maybe there is something that I've missed here but the process of querying the Orchestrator from the chatbot is either

1. have your model locally and write/change tons of code to manage it when stuff changes;
   or
2. use the Orchestration SDK to just shoot to the Orchestator project API and write your code for handling it in chatbot instead.